# Error running OpenTSDB on a Cloudera VMWare CentOS 6.4 4 node cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

I have followed the instructions and successfully installed a Cloudera 4 node Hadoop cluster that includes all the software like HBase etc.

Then installed and built asynchbase and then OpenTSDB. Seems to have worked. However, when I try to run it as per their website "Getting Started Guide", this error is output. Any hints? Thank you.

```
[root@n1 opentsdb-1.1.0]# ./build/tsdb tsd --port=4242
--staticroot=build/staticroot --cachedir="$tsdtmp"2013-05-28 14:31:38,928 INFO  [main] TSDMain: Starting. 2013-05-28 14:31:38,932
INFO  [main] TSDMain: net.opentsdb built at revision  (MODIFIED)
2013-05-28 14:31:38,932 INFO  [main] TSDMain: Built on 2013/05/28
21:21:28 +0000 by
ivanfigueredo@n1.example.com:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build
2013-05-28 14:31:39,063 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.6-1366786, built on 07/29/2012 06:22
GMT 2013-05-28 14:31:39,063 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:host.name=n1.example.com 2013-05-28 14:31:39,063 INFO 
[main] ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_24 2013-05-28
14:31:39,063 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. 2013-05-28 14:31:39,063
INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre
2013-05-28 14:31:39,063 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:java.class.path=/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/hbase/asynchbase-1.4.1.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/guava/guava-13.0.1.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.2.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/logback/logback-classic-1.0.9.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/logback/logback-core-1.0.9.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/netty/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/slf4j/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/suasync/suasync-1.3.1.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../third_party/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.3.6.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/tsdb-1.1.0.jar:/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0/build/../src
2013-05-28 14:31:39,067 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2013-05-28 14:31:39,067 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp 2013-05-28 14:31:39,067 INFO  [main]
ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> 2013-05-28
14:31:39,068 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2013-05-28 14:31:39,068 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:os.arch=amd64 2013-05-28 14:31:39,068 INFO  [main]
ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64
2013-05-28 14:31:39,068 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:user.name=root 2013-05-28 14:31:39,068 INFO  [main]
ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/root 2013-05-28 14:31:39,068
INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Client
environment:user.dir=/home/ivanfigueredo/Downloads/opentsdb-1.1.0
2013-05-28 14:31:39,072 INFO  [main] ZooKeeper: Initiating client
connection, connectString=localhost sessionTimeout=5000
watcher=org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$ZKClient@60491c4c 2013-05-28
14:31:39,086 INFO  [main-SendThread()] ClientCnxn: Opening socket
connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181 2013-05-28
14:31:39,098 INFO  [main] HBaseClient: Need to find the -ROOT- region
2013-05-28 14:31:39,151 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)]
ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing
socket connection and attempting reconnect java.net.ConnectException:
Connection refused  at
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
~[na:1.6.0_24]  at
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592)
~[na:1.6.0_24]  at
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
~[zookeeper-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6-1366786] 2013-05-28 14:31:39,617 INFO 
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Opening socket
connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 2013-05-28 14:31:39,618
INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Socket connection
established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session 2013-05-28
14:31:39,658 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn:
Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181,
sessionid = 0x13eebdd562e000f, negotiated timeout = 5000 2013-05-28
14:31:39,687 INFO  [main-EventThread] HBaseClient: Connecting to
-ROOT- region @ 172.16.156.102:60020 2013-05-28 14:31:39,731 INFO  [main-EventThread] ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13eebdd562e000f closed
2013-05-28 14:31:39,732 INFO  [main-EventThread] ClientCnxn:
EventThread shut down 2013-05-28 14:31:39,768 INFO  [New I/O worker
#4] HBaseClient: Added client for region RegionInfo(table=".META.", region_name=".META.,,1", stop_key=""), which was added to the regions
cache.  Now we know that RegionClient@1237174744(chan=null,
#pending_rpcs=0, #batched=0, #rpcs_inflight=1) is hosting 1 region. 2013-05-28 14:31:39,795 INFO  [main] HBaseClient: Lost connection with
the -ROOT- region Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: Initialization failed   at
net.opentsdb.tools.TSDMain.main(TSDMain.java:176) Caused by:
org.hbase.async.TableNotFoundException: "tsdb"  at
org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$7.call(HBaseClient.java:1718)   at
org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$7.call(HBaseClient.java:1715)   at
com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.doCall(Deferred.java:1262)   at
com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.runCallbacks(Deferred.java:1241)     at
com.stumbleupon.async.Deferred.callback(Deferred.java:989)  at
org.hbase.async.HBaseRpc.callback(HBaseRpc.java:450)    at
org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:1185)     at
org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:82)   at
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
    at
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at
org.hbase.async.RegionClient.handleUpstream(RegionClient.java:1008)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
    at
org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.sendUpstream(HBaseClient.java:2431)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
    at
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at
org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at
org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [root@n1 opentsdb-1.1.0]#
```

Comment: I just realized that I missed the instruction "env COMPRESSION=NONE HBASE_HOME=path/to/hbase-0.94.X ./src/create_table.sh" but I have no idea where HBASE_HOME is. I know where the binary is but that gets confused?

Comment: I figured it out. A little more patience would have worked. In Cloudera, HBase is currently in /usr/bin, so I had to replace /usr in the above command path/to....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in `TableNotFoundException: "tsdb"` so presumably you didn't create the table, or didn't create properly, using the `create_table.sh` script provided with OpenTSDB.